# Can't find a setIndex in SpreadsheetApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to code some protection into a Google Sheets spreadsheet, that will keep the pages in the right order.  I can't protect the entire sheet from modification as it's a group workbook used to organize.. well the organization :P

In google scripts I found the getIndex but i need a setIndex

here is the skeleton of the code, in case I'm not being clear

```
function resetSheetPos() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if s.getSheetName() = "Instructions" {
//the function I can't find would look like this
//s.setIndex(0);
s.activate();  // in case we aren't still looking at the same sheet when it changed it's index
};

if s.getSheetName() = "Notes and Comments" {
//and would be incremented for each sheet
//s.setIndex(1);  
s.activate();  //again only if needed.
};

// and so on for each sheet

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need you use methods on the parent Spreadsheet rather than the Sheets directly.

See moveActiveSheet(index), or possibly insertSheet(index)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#moveActiveSheet(Integer)

Comment: Thanks i Knew this had to be a function somewhere.